# disable Appbar paddings from top and bottom

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to make a box inside the Appbar that takes the full height, as demonstrated below:

[image: demo]

However, the Appbar by default is giving padding from the top, bottom, left, and right to the inner elements, which is resulting in the following unwanted behavior:

[image: demo2]

If I set the prop `disableGutter`, it only disables the padding from the right and left, but it does not disable the paddings from the top and bottom:
[image: demo3]

This is great, but I only now have to disable the padding from the top and bottom.

Full code: [**Or Click Here To See It In Sandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-bose-kqwrcf)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';

export default function Topnav() {
  return (
      <AppBar>
        <Toolbar disableGutters>
          <Typography sx={{ px: 1 }}>About</Typography>
          <Typography sx={{ px: 1 }}>Settings</Typography>
          <Typography sx={{ px: 1, flexGrow: 1 }}>Contact Us</Typography>
          <Box sx={{ background: 'pink' }}>Mr bean</Box>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Use align-self: stretch`

Or you could set your parent div as `alignItems: 'stretch'`, but this would effect all the elements (if that's what you might want)

```
import * as React from "react";
import AppBar from "@mui/material/AppBar";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Toolbar from "@mui/material/Toolbar";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";

export default function Topnav() {
  return (
    <AppBar>
      <Toolbar disableGutters>
        <Typography sx={{ px: 1 }}>About</Typography>
        <Typography sx={{ px: 1 }}>Settings</Typography>
        <Typography sx={{ px: 1, flexGrow: 1 }}>Contact Us</Typography>
        <Box sx={{ background: "pink", alignSelf: 'stretch'}}>

          Mr bean
       
          </Box>
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-water-xr5hdc?file=/src/App.js

(I also centered "mr bean" in above playground)